# Can i modify ReentrantLock so one can use it with try with resources?

Tags: java, reentrantlock, autocloseable

I wanted to ask if this implementation is ok, or maybe there are some issues that can be later problematic.

The idea is to implement a ReentrantLock class that can be used with 'try with resources' and that means that it has to implement the AutoCloseable interface.

In addition, I wanted to ask why in the 'main' method the compiler yields that I have to add a 'catch' clause, because my close method (in MyReentrantLock) doesn't throw an exception.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Ex09ReentrantLock {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class MyReentrantLock extends ReentrantLock implements AutoCloseable{

        public MyReentrantLock() {
            super();
            lock();
        }

        @Override
        public void close(){        
            unlock();
        }   
    }

    public static AutoCloseable lock() {

        var locker = new MyReentrantLock(); //lock() is called in the constructor

        return locker;  //implements AutoCloseable          
    }


    //Demo 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //try(ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock()){} = compiler error

        try(var locker = lock();){          
            //some work...          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

1. Is this implementation ok? (call the lock in the constructor...)
2. Why does the compiler force me to add a catch() clause if my close doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: To answer your second question: It forces you to catch `Exception` because your `#lock()` method returns `AutoCloseable` whose `#close()` method _does_ declare itself to throw the mentioned exception. Since the declared type that's returned is `AutoCloseable` the compiler has no idea the _implementation_ doesn't have a throws declaration. Your method would have to return `MyReentrantLock` for the compiler to know such information.

Answer (score 1):

Locks are meant to be shared.
A lock that locks on construction can only be locked using `new` and thus isn't shareable meaning its useless.

I believe your sample code is for illustration purpose only (but if not, it is definitely a bad idea), to help you more a real case should be given.

Guessing from what you shared, what's closest to what you expressed is the `synchronized` keyword.

In general, locks interactions are difficult to handle, which led to the creation of the synchronized mechanism. Using locks instead should be done in very specific situations where synchronization isn't possible.

Comment: Just to note, in regards to your last paragraph, in Java the `synchronized` mechanism actually predates `Lock` (added in Java 5). If I recall correctly, for a while there the `Lock` API actually performed significantly better under contention but I believe that is no longer true in newer versions (no sources on hand).

Comment: Not sure if i understand correctly what you mean, but `synchronized` uses monitor locks (implemented natively) which is different from the lock API which is a high level. I once built a `Lock` using monitors to be able to use `synchronized` mechanism via Lock API using a somewhat hidden feature enabling to manually enter or exit an object's intrinsic lock.

Comment: Your last paragraph implies, to me, that `synchronized` was created in response to some failings/difficulties of `Lock`. Now, maybe you're referencing programming history in general, but in Java `Lock` was added many versions after `synchronized`. I'm pretty sure `Lock` was added to provide functionality for which `synchronized` is incapable of providing. And my second sentence was relating some benchmarks I remember reading about; when first added, the `Lock` API performed better, under contention, than `synchronized`—but I believe they've matched each other in recent versions of Java.

Comment: Ok thanks, i know understand what predates mean in this case.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Monitor locks are used by low level API for concurrency implementation, for example java.concurrent package implementation. Locks are more of a high level object. Synchronized keyword was high level 'safe' access to low level functionnalities such as Objet.wait/notify.

Comment: For the record, monitor locks may be wrapped inside a Lock class using http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html